# 2d game engine clipping algorithms

Tags: c++, opengl-es, game-engine, clipping

I'm building a 2d game engine using c++ and opengl. Now i have implemented a scene graph and now every node of this graph is being rendered every frame. What are good algorithms for clipping nodes that are outside the viewport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at a most simple level, you could use quadtrees for culling, it has the added bonus of being useful for collision detection as well, Wikipedia has a [page explaining it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).